# Loopback ACL "Authorization Required"

Tags: acl, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I'm using Loopback3. I'm running into an issue with my ACL roles and I'm not sure what I did wrong. I want users in specific roles to be able to write data to the endpoint, and for some reason the user I have set up (which is in one of those roles) cannot write. I get an Authorization Required error.

I have 4 roles:

- admin
- internal
- external
- bot

For this endpoint, all authenticated users can read the data, but only admin, internal, and bot users can write data, and only admin users can delete data.

Here's how I've got my ACLs defined:

```
"acls": [
    {
        "accessType": "*",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$everyone",
        "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "READ",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$authenticated",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "WRITE",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "admin",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "WRITE",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "internal",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "WRITE",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "bot",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "DELETE",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "admin",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
],
```

I have two users set up, one is a bot and one is an admin. When I do a POST request to the API for either user I get the 'Authorization Required' error, even when doing it from the explorer interface. I can do a GET with no problem, but a POST gets a failure.

If I remove all the "WRITE" acl's and replace them with this, doing a POST works.

```
    {
        "accessType": "WRITE",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$authenticated",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
```

So, I *can* make it happen, but I don't know why my custom roles are failing.

Edit: Here is how I created the users, since I don't actually have any kind of interface built yet.

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    let today = new Date();

    let admin = {
        name: 'admin',
        description: 'admin users',
        created: today.toJSON(),
        modified: today.toJSON()
    };

    let internal = {
        name: 'internal',
        description: 'Internal users',
        created: today.toJSON(),
        modified: today.toJSON()
    };

    let external = {
        name: 'external',
        description: 'external users',
        created: today.toJSON(),
        modified: today.toJSON()
    };

    let bot = {
        name: 'bot',
        description: 'robots',
        created: today.toJSON(),
        modified: today.toJSON()
    };

    let model = app.models.user;

    model.create([
        {username: 'bot', email: 'example@example.com', password: 'test123'},
        {username: 'admin', email: 'example2@example.com', password: 'test123'},
        {username: 'iAdmin', email: 'example3@example.com', password: 'test123'},
        {username: 'eUser', email: 'example4@example.com', password: 'test123'},
    ], function(err, users) {
        if (err) throw err;

        app.models.Role.create(bot, function (err, botRole) {
            if (err) throw err;

            botRole.principals.create({principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.user, principalID: users[0].id}, function(err, principal) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });

        app.models.Role.create(admin, function (err, adminRole) {
            if (err) throw err;

            adminRole.principals.create({principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.user, PrincipalID: users[1].id}, function(err, principal) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });

        app.models.Role.create(admin, function (err, internalRole) {
            if (err) throw err;

            internalRole.principals.create({principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.user, PrincipalID: users[2].id}, function(err, principal) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });

        app.models.Role.create(external, function (err, externalRole) {
            if (err) throw err;

            externalRole.principals.create({principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.user, PrincipalID: users[3].id}, function(err, principal) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Possibly the problem is where you created the roles and associated it to the user.

Comment: Possibly, I've added the script I used to create the users in the first place.

Comment: I believe they are supposed to be `app.models.RoleMapping.USER` instead of `app.models.RoleMapping.user`

Comment: Good catch! I made the change for that but it still doesn't seem to have affected anything.

Comment: It's like the dynamic roles that Loopback already has in it (like `$everyone` and `$authenticated`) work just fine but all of my custom roles are ignored.

Comment: @Lisa , I am also newly started working loopback 3 and facing same kind of challenge . Could you please share working example with me so it will help . Please,kindly share on kharade.pramod91@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issues I was experiencing revolved around the following items:

1. Use `app.models.RoleMapping.USER` instead of `app.models.RoleMapping.user` (which was changed in the codebase early on)
2. Use `principalId` instead of `principalID`

Since the rest of the ACLs had been removed from the application some time ago due to them not working, I can't state whether or not they were also contributing to the problems, but I will be adding them in over time making sure to use the correct permissions for LB3.

Comment: What was the issue by the way? I know this is an old question and answer, but I am facing similar issues.

Comment: @PrivateOmega If I remember right, it was simply LoopBack getting upset about case. As I described in point 1, I needed to have `USER` instead of `user`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between roles and dynamic roles/states ($everyone and $authenticated), while your roles get stored in a table to keep the association with the user $everyone and $authenticated is just a state of the user. Look at a table named "RoleMapping", if that is correct. Also if you have a custom Role, create a custom RoleResolver.

There is really good documentation, and really not that hard to get started in Loopback 3.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html

This example gave me a great understanding of roles in general:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/blob/master/server/boot/role-resolver.js

It's an entire project so you can check out the models there aswell.

Answer (score 0):

this is how your two table should look like :

```
GET role -->> [table - role]

[
  {
    "roleId": 1,
    "name": "admin",
    "description": "admin",
    "created": "2016-08-23T16:46:07.572Z",
    "modified": "2016-08-23T16:46:07.572Z"
  },
  {
    "roleId": 2,
    "name": "internal",
    "description": "internal",
    "created": "2016-08-23T16:46:07.574Z",
    "modified": "2016-08-23T16:46:07.574Z"
  }
]


Get Role Mapping  [table- user-role]-->>

[
  {
    "userRoleId": 123,
    "roleId": 2, //id of role i.e. 1 for admin 
    "principalType": "USER",
    "principalId": "1234",
    "created": null,
    "modified": null
  },
  ..
  ...
]
```

So by looking at your code, I can say that you are not adding roleId into roleMapping table.

First add all roles in roles table,

Now create user and add entry of that user in role mapping table and assign one roleID to it, see in above code where roleId 1 denotes Admin Role.

Comment: My RoleMapping table has the roleId field populated, but the principalId field is not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are some syntax and logic error your code!

1. app.models.RoleMapping.USER instead of app.models.RoleMapping.user (as @Farid said).
2. There is no "DELETE" acceessType in loopback acl. you should use "*", "READ", "WRITE" or "EXECUTE" for accesType value. "WRITE" support "create", "updateAttributes", "upsert" and "destroyById" resoueces. (more details in [loopback documentation](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Controlling-data-access.html)).

Change the acl such following code:

`"acls": [
    {
        "accessType": "*",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$everyone",
        "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "READ",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$authenticated",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "*",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "admin",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "internal",
        "permission": "ALLOW",
        "property": ["create", "updateAttributes", "upsert"]
    },
    {
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "bot",
        "permission": "ALLOW",
        "property": ["create", "updateAttributes", "upsert"]
    }
]`

1. Finally, ensure that you perform role and roleMapping correctly.